# knitr parses extra verbatim documentclass

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'd like to include an example of complete LaTeX code inside an Rnw document that is parsed using knitr.

My .Rnw file is shown here (I really want to include a bunch of R code as well but this minimal example shows my problem)

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}    
Recursiveness, see     
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Recursiveness
\end{document}
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

When I run `knitr test.Rnw` I get a `.tex` file where the second `documentclass` is replaced (see below, where the top of the `.tex` file is shown). I'm pretty sure that this is `knitr` that replaces the litaral string `\documentclass` with its own macro that and it does not realize that it shouldn't be parsen when inside the verbatim environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\begin{document}

Recursiveness, see 

\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}\usepackage[]{graphicx}\usepackage[]{color}
%% maxwidth is the original width if it is less than linewidth
%% otherwise use linewidth (to make sure the graphics do not exceed the margin)
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{ %
  \ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth
    \linewidth
  \else
    \Gin@nat@width
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Is it possible to circumvent this? I tried to insert a zero-width space character in the middle of `documentclass` but that gave me a bunch of headaches with the parsing.

Comment: Sorry, no time for a longer answer, but adding a chunk with `knitr::opts_knit$set(self.contained = FALSE)` is a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and should be [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/7d0f080fa45a059124b5718083e036d8aee40f38) in the current [development version of **knitr**](https://github.com/yihui/knitr) (>= 1.12.22) now.